# Create unique ObjectId during $project pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregation framework query that is summarizing certain document data into a lookup set. Unfortunately, I can't provide the data since it's company-related. Here is the query and data fragment from the last stages of the pipeline:

```
...
{ $group: { _id: "$SectionId", "Questions": { $addToSet: "$Questions" } } },
{ $unwind: "$Questions" },
```

which returns data like this: **Note that `_id` is not unique.**

```
{
    "_id" : "Tonometry",
    "Questions" : {
        "MappingId" : "Exophoria",
        "PositiveLabel" : "Positive",
        "NegativeLabel" : "Negative"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "Tonometry",
    "Questions" : {
        "MappingId" : "Heterophoria",
        "PositiveLabel" : "Positive",
        "NegativeLabel" : "Negative"
    }
},
```

The next stage in the pipeline is this:

```
{
    $project: {
        "_id": 1,
        "id": ObjectId(),
        "SectionId": "$_id",
        "MappingId": "$Questions.MappingId",
        "PositiveLabel": "$Questions.PositiveLabel",
        "NegativeLabel": "$Questions.NegativeLabel",
    }
},
```

which produces:

```
{
    "_id" : "Tonometry",
    "id" : ObjectId("5d1cf66cf526f23524f865c6"),
    "SectionId" : "Tonometry",
    "MappingId" : "Exophoria",
    "PositiveLabel" : "Positive",
    "NegativeLabel" : "Negative"
},
{
    "_id" : "Tonometry",
    "id" : ObjectId("5d1cf66cf526f23524f865c6"),
    "SectionId" : "Tonometry",
    "MappingId" : "Heterophoria",
    "PositiveLabel" : "Positive",
    "NegativeLabel" : "Negative"
},
```

I tried creating a new field `Id` that has a unique ObjectId but unfortunately just re-uses the same ObjectId in all the nodes. This is important because when I attempt to use `$out`, it requires a unique `_id`.

How do I add a unique ObjectId to each node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)** does not need a unique `_id`, you can use **[`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)** together with **[`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#exp._S_mergeObjects)** prior to **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)** pipeline, this will merge the `Question` document into the desired document without an `_id` field and **[`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)** will create the `_id` field for you in the new collection:

```
[
    ....
    { "$group": { "_id": "$SectionId", "Questions": { "$addToSet": "$Questions" } } },
    { "$unwind": "$Questions" },
    { "$replaceRoot": { 
        "newRoot": { 
            "$mergeObjects": [ 
                { "Section": "$_id" }, 
                "$Questions" 
             ] 
        } 
    } },
    { "$out": "new-collection" }
]
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay - was on vacation! I just tried your suggestion but unfortunately, we're still running version 3.4 and `$mergeObjects` is not supported. I'll try upgrading my local install to v3.6 and give it a go.

Comment: I looked over my code again based on your solution and did this under v3.4 and it worked:
      {
            $project: {
                "_id": 0,
                "SectionId": "$_id",
                "MappingId": "$Questions.MappingId",
                "PositiveLabel": "$Questions.PositiveLabel",
                "NegativeLabel": "$Questions.NegativeLabel",
            }
        },
So I have a solution in either v3.4 or 3.6 but also was introduced to a new mongo command!